# Lock on an object that might change during code execution

Tags: c#, multithreading

Let's suppose I have a thread that locks on an object reference

Thread #1

```
lock(myObj) { ... }
```

later in code I have `myObj = new XYZObj();`

and then Thread #2 locks on it

```
lock(myObj) { ... }
```

Will this code be thread safe, if the object reference has changed? When the object reference changes, the first lock is still valid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Locks work on instances, not variables.
The `lock` statement will hold its own reference to the instance so that it will only exit the instance you entered.

The [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664735%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) says:

> where x is an expression of a reference-type, is precisely equivalent
>   to
>
> ```
> System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x);
> try {
>    ...
> }
> finally {
>    System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x);
> }
> ```
>
> **except that x is only evaluated once.**

If you re-assign the variable between the two locks, you will get two valid locks on two different instances.

In general, however, you should never do that; it's a recipe for subtle bugs and race conditions.
You should only lock on dedicated readonly lock objects.

Comment: You wrote *will hold its own reference to the variable*, but I assume you meant **holds a variable referencing the same object** ;)

Answer (score 4):

No. They will both be locking on different objects.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

> Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private
>   static object variable to protect data common to all instances.

Answer (score 2):

> Will this code be thread safe

The statement `lock(myObj) { ... }` is only safe until a new object reference is assigned to the `myObj` variable. **Addition:** Also, it's only safe if any data shared between threads that is used non-atomically mutating inside a lock on an object is **only** used non-atomically mutating inside locks on that same object.

So, every time you enter a lock for `myObj`, the actual referenced object is what is being used for the lock, not your variable. If you change the variable to reference a new object, then you're effectively locking different objects in different locks, which obviously isn't what you wanted. But, then again, the next time you come back to the first lock, the first and second lock object *might* be in sync again, and so it'll be safe again. Maybe!

As you can see, that behavior is completely broken. Is this a hypothetical question or are you really doing like that?

Comment: Actually, no; it depends what the code does.  Blindly slapping locks everywhere does not make a program thread-safe.

Comment: @SLaks: Of course, I tried to clarify in **Addition:** above. Thanks.