# Is this a correct use of multithreading design? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm building a small chat program that consists of a server and client.  The server keeps a list of clients that it interacts with.

I've got two worker threads on the server.  One handles incoming client connections.  The other handles incoming client messages.

Now, since both threads interact with a List called 'clients', I've done something like this.

```
// The clients list looks something like this...
List<TcpClient> clients;

// This is running on one thread.
ConnectionHandler()
{
    while(true)
    {
        // Wait for client to connect, etc. etc.

        // Now, add the client to my clients List.
        lock(clients)clients.Add(myNewClient);
    }
}

// This is running on another thread.
ClientHandler()
{
    while(true)
    {
        lock(clients)
        {
            /*
            This will be handling things like incoming messages
            and clients disconnecting (clients being removed from
            the 'clients' List
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a correct use of locks to prevent my List from being altered by two different threads at once?

I haven't had any problems doing this so far, but I just want to make sure it's correct.

Comment: Consider using System.Collections.Concurrent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is correct, but make sure that ClientHandler does not hold the lock for too long. It should never hold the lock while blocking (e.g. caused by an IO operation on a socket). If you violate this rule you will find your throughput being destroyed (still maintaining correctness).

Comment: Right, I've avoided blocking while it's locked by checking if DataAvailable is true on the TcpClient stream before potentially calling Read.

Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Not only do this, but as long as you do not manipulate the clients list, do not lock it. Keep as much to a client in an instance on it's own and refrence this instance in the handler. no need ot lock the clients list (in this way you would only handl one request at a time - there would be no need for multithreading

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon But what if I'm iterating through the clients in a for loop?  It should be inside a lock because I don't want the list changing during the loop, right?

Comment: @Inlinevoid, yes. But be sure not to block inside the body of your loop. If you need to do some processing for each client consider making a local copy of your list and then exit then lock quickly.

Comment: @usr Alright.  Let's say iterating through the loop of clients and doing some heavy processing on each client has the potential to sometimes take about 2-3 seconds to finish the whole loop, that just means the newly connecting clients would have to wait that 2-3 seconds to successfully connect, right?  Or are there other dangers of locking for too long? (maybe the client trying to connect would drop?)

Comment: Blocking for 2-3s means that a) new connections can't be set up (probably not a problem) b) existing connections cannot execute their ClientHandler code (this is likely to be a problem).

Comment: @usr Alright, makes sense.  I'll be sure to keep this in mind.

Comment: If you iterate through it of course you have to lock. But if not, just keep a thread local copy of the client descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have single writer and multiple readers? Have a look at [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) and [this collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Looks kinda OK.  Chat servers are periously tricky for multithreadedly-challenged.  Exceptions could be raised inside locks, for example, when a server-client socket object gets a disconnect but, before its thread can remove the object from the list, another thread locks the list and tries to write to the disconnected socket.

Answer (score 0):

A note (on top) - since you don't initialize the field (ie I don't see how you do it, when you might destroy and re-initialize etc.) - **make sure you're locking the same instance**, e.g. see this [Lock on an object that might change during code execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578870/lock-on-an-object-that-might-change-during-code-execution)

Comment: `I don't see how you do it, when you might destroy and re-initialize etc.`  then OP would loose all of the references to clients

Comment: not necessarily :) - he might just copy, use linq to return new List, (keep references) etc.

Comment: funny, `clients=clients.SomeLinq()`. Just making a wild assumption that OP would write such a really bad code, and answering it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me but I would make this correction:

```
private readonly List<TcpClient> clients = new List<TcpClient>();
```

You can also create the list in the constructor but keep it as **readonly**. This is key to make sure you're locking on the same object. Otherwise, if you happen recreate `clients` list, your code would stop being thread safe.